# C# send Email line break in body ignored when using command line

Tags: c#, sendmail, mailmessage

I am using C# MailMessage library to send email but I am facing issues when trying to call this .exe from command line with line breaks in it, it ignores the lines breaks. Can anyone help to find the root cause?

Comment: Escape the special chars in your command line call maybe? (\\t\\r\\n for example)

Comment: \\t\\r\\n did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the terminal you are using. For example, with bash, you would specify your string using single quotations, preceded by `$`, for example:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var arg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(arg);   
    }
}
```

```
> SomeApp.exe $'One\r\n\r\nTwo\r\n\r\n'
One

Two
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure about other terminals/operation systems and dont have the ability to test them.

Comment: I am using Windows command prompt

Comment: Check out https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html for possible solutions. Maybe the `^` escape character is what you need?

Comment: tried various approaches but still does not work.

Comment: Would it be easier for you to transform my command line command to something which works on windows cmd

Comment: The problem is that while I can search for solutions, I cannot test them, because I don't have a Windows machine. From [this page](https://www.shellhacks.com/windows-echo-newline-line-break-n-cmd-powershell/), you could try with PowerShell and use `\`n`, or with CMD you could try multiple echo statements (also on same page)